# celery task and django queryset cache

Tags: python, mysql, django, celery

I am trying to get celery to work but I have some issues, which I don't quite understand.

I am inheriting a model from a 3rd party package

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def do(self, a=1, b=2):
        return a + b
```

Then;

```
from thirdpartypackage.models import BaseModel

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    some_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    @current_app.task(filter=task_method):
    def do(self, a=1, b=1):
        self.some_field = super(MyModel, self).do(a=a, b=b)
        self.save()
```

Now whenever I run a task that involves a db query, for example:

```
def my_view(request, pk=None):
    obj = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=pk)

    obj.do.delay(a=2, b=4)

    return HttpResponse('the answer is: {}'.format(obj.some_field))
```

I see the task pop up in celery (flower), but the actual http response does not update the result, after I refresh heavily I see the result update, although this seems unreliable.

Stranger so, on a real server (apache in my case) this doesn't do seem to do the trick (refreshing), although flower says 'success'. When I move into shell (python manage.py shell) and call the job directly, I do see the result immediately.

Is there anything about django's/mysql caching I should know? How do I force updates?

If I call the function directly (no delay) it works immediately as expected:

```
def my_view(request, pk=None):
    obj = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=pk)

    obj.do(a=2, b=4)

    return HttpResponse('the answer is: {}'.format(obj.some_field))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem with your DB caching. The problem is that you're reading the value and returning it in `HttpResponse` **before Celery has a chance to run it**. `task.delay()` is an asynchronous call that creates a job and **returns immediately**. The actual job needs to be picked up by a worker and executed, which often happens with some processing delay.

You can solve this using various methods, e.g. using Javascript and AJAX to update the frontend once the job has finished.

Comment: although valid your point doesn't seem to be causing the issue. I do see the job finish nearly instantly (celery flower) and as I covered, refreshing doesn't seem to help on the apache webserver, but thanks I will investigate further

Comment: Be careful with interpreting the results saying the job **is finished**. By default, tasks are being **acknowledged immediately** when popped out of the queue, unless you explicitly specify that they are idempotent by setting `acks_late` switch on. Read more here: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html